# git says untracked content and cant add it to repo

Tags: git

There is a folder that shows as `modified:   predis (modified content)` when I do `git status`.

After doing `git add .`, it still shows as `(untracked content)`.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong or how I can add this folder?

Comment: `git add predis`? Is `predis` in the current wording directory when you run `git add .`?

Comment: Yes it is. It's in the same folder as all other files/folders in this repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like "predis" is a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). Hence, your main repo is not tracking directly that submodule.

What you actually "add" is a commit pointer of that submodule. Now, if you want to actually commit/push the content of that submodule then you will have to go to that directory

```
$cd predis
$git status #this will show you the list of modified files
$git add [whatever you want to add]
$git commit -m "your message"
$git push # where? I don't know your project specifications
```

Now, when you go to your main project directory

```
$cd ..
$git add predis
$git commit
$git push
$git status
```

You should see a clean status (nothing to commit).

Comment: close! now status returns: `modified:   predis (new commits)`

Comment: $git push
then your project should be clean

Comment: what is the output of git status?

Comment: I guess it will say modified: predis (new commits), which means that your submodule now have new changes, which means that your repo is noticing "a new" version of the submodule, now you make your repo to use that version of the submodule by doing a regular "git add predis",  git commit, git push.

Comment: thanks! I guess I had to add/commit a few times, but now it's in.

Answer (score 0):

This is git submodule, open this directory and you will find `.git` and/or `.gitignore` file in this directory, either remove the `.git` directory from this **predis** directory or add **predis** to `.gitignore` file.